# Show alert view and stay on same view controller when cancel is pushed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm using the storyboard with 2 view controllers connected to each other with a segue. On the first view controller there is a button and if you click on that button it goes to the second view controller. The problem is that I want to pop up an alert view, I tried to show the alertview in the  `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method but the problem with this is that it goes to the second view controller and then pops up the alert view. I want it to pop up on the first view controller and if you push the cancel button from the alert view it still stays on the first view controller. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing this you need do something like:

- Remove the segues from the button on the story board.
- Implement an `IBAction` for that button and show alert there
- Using the `clickedButtonAtIndex` delegate method of `UIAlertView` check the button pressed. If user press Ok go to next view

Add the `IBAction` like:

```
- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender
{
   UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can I Move ?"
                                                  message:nil
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
   [message show];
}
```

And implement the delegate method like:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Other View"] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**Note:** Also you can use [performSegueWithIdentifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for moving to next view

Comment: and how do I connect the next view controller with the button then after the user pushed 'OK'?

Comment: This seems to work but if I push "OK" the alert view just closes instead of going to the next view... I changed the ViewControllerWithIdentifier with the Storyboard ID

Comment: Storyboard ID of another view. Also check whether the if condition is executing.

Comment: I took the storyboard ID from the view controller that needs to be loaded

Comment: @Shinonuma: Check whether the if condition is working or not. Put a breakpoint or NSLog inside the if condition

Comment: @Shinonuma: With pleasure :) All the best

Answer (score 2):

You need to display the alert as a result of the button tap and act as the delegate for the alert. Only when you get the alert completion delegate callback (alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:) do you decide whether you should trigger the segue or do nothing.